# Can I copy paste my c# application to MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin.ios

I have very little information about MonoTouch by use of C#.

my question is, can I copy paste all of my code from visual studio in to the MonoTouch? 
dose my application will compile the same as visual studio? how dose it really work, when I copy paste my application from asp.net/c# to MonoTouch? Do I need to write some extra code inside my application in order to make it works in ipad and iphone or android?

Comment: @Sam - An ASP.NET application is not going to port very easily into a iOS MonoTouch application.  For the same reason it would not port easily into a WinForm/WPF application its a web application.

Comment: I am very new to Mono so I though someone who tried could help me how to start.  It save my time!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asp.net is a web based framework for .net and monotouch is a toolkit for iphone using .net

so yes you can copy and paste, and no it won't compile straight out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions? so I do need to write some extra code inside my application then how dose it really work? could you please give me some idea! Many thanks

Comment: the amount of code needed will vary. but if you have coded your app correctly you would be able to port the classes over and then build the interface around that.